# Entity Framework 4.2 one-to-many, no DbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework, frameworks, entity

I'm trying to setup a one-to-many relationship with EF 4.2, but it just won't work.
Some data:

```
table "BugNet_Projects"
ProjectManagerUserId uniqueidentifier not null

table "aspnet_Users"
UserId uniqueidentifier not null
```

```cs
class Project
{
    [ForeignKey("ProjectManagerUserId")]
    public User ProjectManager { get; set; }
    public Guid ProjectManagerUserId { get; set; }
}

class User
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().Map(p => p.ToTable("BugNet_Projects"));
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Map(u => u.ToTable("aspnet_Users"));
}
```

Note the User entity/aspnet_Users table does not have a reference to Projects. There is a FK in the database from ProjectManagerUserId to UserId. When I request a Project from the Context (with .Include("ProjectManager")), the ProjectManager property is always null. The ProjectManagerUserId property is correctly filled with a GUID.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, your navigation properties have to be marked as virtual:

```
public class Project
{
    [ForeignKey("ProjectManagerUserId")]
    public virtual User ProjectManager { get; set; }
    public Guid ProjectManagerUserId { get; set; }
}
```

Why?

At runtime, EF 4.2 makes a subclass and overrides this property in order to populate it from the db (making Include work for eager loading, etc).